# "Required Reviews Completed"

Tags: peer-review

"Required Reviews Completed" Is that normal that this status lasts more than one month after Major Revision?

Thank you for your contribution

Comment: Pretty much anything can happen with reviews and editors. The editor may still have questions. If they are an academic, they might be busy. Lots of things. You can ask for an update, of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"**Required review completed**" means that the reviewers who were assigned to review your paper have all submitted their reviews. The next step is that the editor who is handling your paper should take a decision based on these reviews such as "accept", "reject", "minor/major revision", or invite more reviewers.

It is a bit unusual that it takes 1 month after the reviews are completed. From my experience (as author of more than 200 papers and as editor-in-chief of some journal) it is usually more like a few days or a week but it can vary depending on the journal. There can be various reasons why there is a long delay such as the handling editor being very busy.

What you should do is to send an e-mail to the editor to let him/her know that your paper is waiting with that status for over a month. Write a polite e-mail and ask gently to check what is going on with your paper. I did that recently for a paper that was in that situation for 3 months... The editor told me that he was busy and since he was only a guest-editor he did not handle the job quickly, but after my e-mail, he processed it quickly. Don't send more than 1 e-mail because editors are usually very busy.